# "I know where you work at" vs. "I know where you work"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which one is correct?

> 1. I don't need to know where you work at.
> 2. I don't need to know where you work.

Could you also please tell me about this rule is called in grammar so I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copyeditor in me observes that your *at* there adds nothing to the sentence: leave it out.

It’s also something of a **shibboleth** whose use will mark you as “poorly educated”, because these things are expected to have been corrected in the course of proper schooling. The same is true with questions like “Where are you at?”  Here again that  *at* at the end adds nothing — or at least, nothing good — and should be omitted.

Once upon a time, surely aeons ago now, there was something of a hipster phrase about “where it’s at”, referring to some location or event or even style that was supposed to be “really happening”.  Unless you’re trying to faithfully recreate the special slang from that period in history, I would avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

When we use the Interrogative Pronoun "Where," we normally don't include the Prepositions, whether it's in the form of Questions, Noun Clauses or Noun Phrases.

Example:

> Where are you going? (no "to")
>
> Where do youlive? (no "in")

Compare these with:

> *Which* restaurant are you going *to*?
>
> *What* city do you live *in*?

However, we do use them to ask about origins:

> *Where* are you *from*?

Comment: **Where** is not a pronoun, it is an adverb. 1) "Where" cannot be replaced by a noun, 2. "Where" cannot be used as a subject or object of a verb - this can be shown by "Where **is** the dog?" but "Where **are** the dogs?" in which "the dog/dogs" is the subject. -- Where means "at which place". -- As "where" has also encompassed the meaning of "whither" and "whence" it can also mean "from which place" and "to which place."